# R indexing by column name from a list not working

Tags: r, list, indexing

Suppose I have a dataset,
CT_Data, in list format with internet1_group as an item in the list such that:

```
 $ internet1_group : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 3 1 2 1 1 3 2 1 2 1 ...
```

I will be creating Dependent_Variable_List as a character with the following value:

```
 Dependent_Variable_List <- Dependent_Variable_List[Dependent_Variable_List %in% colnames(CT_Data)]

 Dependent_Variable_List
 [1] "internet1_group"
```

Now I'm trying to index Dependent_Variable levels in dataset CT_Data, and store the levels in CT_Vars list.

```
CT_Vars <- list()
CT_Vars[["DV_Levels"]] <- levels(CT_Data[, Dependent_Variable_List])
```

I keep on getting `CT_Vars[["DV_Levels"]]` as `NULL`, could anyone help me to debug the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're saying that CT_Data is a list, but your call is structured for a data frame. Does this work? If not, can you run `dput(CT_Data)` and paste the results in your question?

```
CT_Vars[["DV_Levels"]] <- levels(CT_Data[[Dependent_Variable_List]])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing it out! I used `CT_Data <- data.frame(CT_Data, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` before running the code, and now it is working. I should be more careful with the types.